# Getting true class labels after saving model for text-classification

Tags: python, nlp, keras, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I am doing text-classification. I have used `Conv1D` layer on top of Keras `Embedding` layer. I am getting a validation accuracy of 0.68.This is the [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxe63rkqkaqji1x/emotion_merged_dataset.csv?dl=0) I am using. This is the code I am using:

```
   #Processing
import pandas as pd
import pickle

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.layers import Embedding,Flatten,Dense,Conv1D,MaxPooling1D,GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.models import load_model

# df = pd.read_csv('text_emotion.csv')
#
# df.drop(['tweet_id', 'author'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# df = df[~df['sentiment'].isin(['empty', 'enthusiasm', 'boredom', 'anger'])]

# df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df=pd.read_csv('emotion_merged_dataset.csv')
labels = df['sentiment']
# texts = df['content']
texts=df['text']
print (texts.shape)
#############################################
tokenizer = Tokenizer(3000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
# print(sequences)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# with open('word_index.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
#     word_index_new = pickle.load(handle)

# print (word_index == word_index_new)

# print('Word index: '+str(word_index))
# print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))

data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=37)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(labels)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(labels)

from keras.utils import np_utils

labels = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
print ('Labels: '+str(labels))

print('Shape of data tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', labels.shape)
print('data: '+str(data))

indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices]
# print ('data:'+str(data[0]))
labels = labels[indices]
print(labels.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(3000, 300, input_length=37))
# model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Conv1D(32,7,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(32,7,activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(labels.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, labels, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, batch_size=100)
model.save('model_keras_embedding_cnn.h5')
print (model.summary())
```

I am pickling the tokenizer and saving the model. Then I am using the tokenizer to pre-process a sample input sentence to check my model.Here is the code below for testing:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import pickle
model = load_model('model_keras_embedding_cnn.h5')
texts='I am really sad'
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer_new = pickle.load(handle)
tokenizer_new.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer_new.texts_to_sequences(texts)
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=37)
print (model.predict_classes(data,verbose=10))
```

I am getting an output like:

```
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5].
```

How can I get true class labels(like fear,anger,etc)?
Is my approach correct i.e. saving the tokenizer and using it again? Have I messed up somewhere conceptually? 
[Edit] I used inverse_transform at the recommendation of JARS:

```
print (encoder_new.inverse_transform(pred))
```

The output was this:

```
['neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral'
 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral' 'neutral'
 'neutral']
```

Can someone explain the output?

Comment: `label_encoder.inverse_transform(id)` gives you the true class label.

Comment: @JARS Can you answer that with respect to my code? Do I also need to pickle my LabelEncoder object? Also, the labels have been one-hot encoded so I doubt it would work.

Comment: The label encoder contains the dictionary of class names vs labels, which you can get by calling inverse_transform. So if you pickle label_encoder and run `inverse_transform`, I believe this should work.

Comment: But if you check my code, I have one-hot encoded my labels also. They are in this format:[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  0.  0.]]. How can inverse_transform work on this? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `predict_classes` "undoes" the one-hot encoding, so in my understanding you can apply the `inverse_transform` to those values.

Comment: Can you tell why I am getting fifteen 5s as the output? I should be getting back a single number corresponding to the class right? And why 15? I have 8 class labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credit of this answer goes to [JARS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5541673/jars). So my input should have been

```
texts=['I am very happy with the result']
```

And the result is:

```
['joy']
```

The whole code is:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import pickle
model = load_model('model_keras_embedding_cnn.h5')
texts=['I am very happy with the result']
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer_new = pickle.load(handle)
with open('encoder.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    encoder_new = pickle.load(handle)
tokenizer_new.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer_new.texts_to_sequences(texts)
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=37)
pred=model.predict_classes(data)
print (encoder_new.inverse_transform(pred))
```

If you count the number of characters in the sentence you will find:
15 characters and that is the number of output I was getting.